# How could I insert NULL for ""

Tags: sql-server

I have a bit column in Sql Server table. It will store either 1, 0 or null.

From the front end, I will be passing `True`, `False` or `""`

How could I insert value with `""` as  `NULL`.

Currently it is storing NULL for False and `""`

My current code is given below

```
INSERT INTO Details(Name, YesNo)  
VALUES ('John', NULLIF(@YesNoNull, ''));
```

Comment: What is your front end? Most modern languages have a representation of `DBNULL`...

Comment: What's the declared type of `@YesNoNull`?

Comment: What would be wrong with passing in the actual value you want to put in from the front end. `1`, `0`, or `NULL`?

Comment: From C#.Net front end, I am passing data as XML and XML contains "True" , "False" or "". In Sql Server, I have a stored procedure which uses OPENXML and runs through Cursor for Temp Table and inserts/updates the records.

Comment: What is wrong with your current code? It looks like it will insert NULL instead of empty string just fine.

Comment: I want to insert NULL for "" as the subject says. But here the problem is  it is passing NULL to the table where in XML it is False or ""

Comment: What type is @YesNoNull?

Comment: @YesNoNull is a BIT datatype

Comment: Hi @Bridge, the current code treats 0 as Null and also "" as Null.  As a result, I will get records as 1, Null and Null for True, False and ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sql treats '' as false. so in your query when @YesNoNull is False NULLIF(@YesNoNull, '') evaluates to true and thus returns NULL and so NULL is getting stored in db even when it is False.

You would need to do this. Change it as it suits you.

```
DECLARE @YesNoNull VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @YNN BIT
SELECT @YesNoNull = <VALUE FROM XML)
SELECT @YNN = CASE @YesNoNull 
        WHEN 'True' THEN 1
        WHEN 'False' THEN 0
        WHEN '' THEN NULL
    END
INSERT INTO Details(Name, YesNo)  
VALUES ('John', @YNN);
```

Comment: I have a point here. Before framing XML, the values are True, False and null in C#. After framing of XML, it will be automatically changed to "1", "0" and "". With this XML, I need to use OPENXML in SQL Stored procedure and run through the cursor and store the values as 1, 0 and  Null. Sorry for the inconvenience caused and there is no point in writing case function here.

Comment: Can you post the piece of stored procedure where the action is taking place?

Comment: It is resolved. I used "1" and 1 for varchar and bit values. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

looks like you have declared `@YesNoNull` as `BIT`, instead declare it as `VARCHAR(1)`, and your code will work ok. The issue is because `NULLIF` treats `''` as `0`.